# Predictive Modelling in R

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I am new to R and I am trying to do some predictive modelling on data set which has 16 feature variables and the target value is numeric in R. I am not sure if the steps I am following will help me to fit the model in the best possible way.

1. Handling the missing values: The data had a lot of missing values, so I replaced it with the mean of the column. Is this a right way to handle missing values?
2. Used Stepwise Regression to select the right set of most predictive variables in a model. Is there any better way to decide the variables than Stepwise regression.
3. After deciding the variables, I used glm() function to fit the model.

Can someone please help me to understand the process of predictive modeling in R.

I was actually following the below document to get a sense of predictive modelling.
http://blog.fractalanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Predictive_Analytics_Methdology_Using_R_v1.0.pdf

Comment: The answer to (1) is "absolutely not"  If a value is missing, why would you assign it an arbitrary value? No one knows what it is, and if you change it to a number of your own choosing, you've completely changed the results of your forthcoming analysis.

Comment: Many (modern) statisticians hate stepwise regression with a vengeance. So you get another "absolutely not" on (2) as well.

Comment: A couple of papers that may be helpful/interesting: "Risk prediction models: I and II" - Moons and "The search for stable prognostic models in multiple imputed data sets" - Vergouw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad and very basic question so I will recommend a very broad and basic book - but one that addresses your question thoroughly:

[Predictive Analytics For Dummies](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118728963.html) by Anasse Bari, Mohamed Chaouchi, Tommy Jung

See especially Chapter 14: Predictive Modeling with R

Hope that helps to get you started...

*Addendum*
Concerning your comment the following two resources a also well worth a look:

- [An introduction to data science](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6iefdnF22XQeVZDSkxjZ0Z5VUE/edit) by Jeff Stanton (free ebook)
- [Rattle](http://rattle.togaware.com/) - sophisticated data mining user interface with lots of additional material (mostly free)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for some material which will help me proceed. I don't have access to this book right now. It would be great if you could suggest some more references?

Comment: @NikitaSinnarkar: Updated my answer accordingly, hope that helps :-)